# How to check module location in python

Tags: python, module, path

After importing module `foo`, I can check its location/path by looking at `foo.__path__`.

```
python3
>>> import foo
>>> foo.__path__
['/home/joe/Py3/foo']
```

How do I check the location/path from within `foo`?

Comment: If you want the *location*, use `os.path.abspath(__file__)`.

Comment: Thank you. That does the trick.